# Pound, HTTPs and Varnish

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, azure, varnish, pound

I'm configuring a proxy, and trying to workout how to use a SSL Cert for Pound. Or whether its even needed?

At this stage the proxy simply points to the web server - we are likely to need more web servers in the near future, so need to workout how to set this up. Systems running on Azure, Proxy is Ubuntu, Pound is intended to point at varnish. Certificate is a QuickSSL Premium from ssls.com (Have I bought the wrong cert?)

The Cert was generated on from a request on a Windows server, this is installed and works (Skipping the Proxy) Is it possible to use this cert on another machine (i.e. Proxy)?

What would be the best way to do this? Is it possible to have a cert on Multiple Machines (Load Balanced or other).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still didn't get any Answers on this, but found that regenerating the cert with the Ubuntu (openssl) server key made the cert work on that as well as the windows Machine.

Seems much easier and maintainable to put these in as few places as possible so have terminated the SSL at the Proxy.